# How to tell which picture was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
                var pic3 = document.createElement("IMG");
                pic3.setAttribute("src", "img/mutantpre.jpg");
                pic3.setAttribute("onclick", "display()");
                pic3.setAttribute("id", "mutantpre");
                pic3.setAttribute("height", "250px");
                pic3.setAttribute("width", "150px");
                document.getElementById("product4").appendChild(pic3);
```

Im trying to create a function to set all pictures to hidden when this one is clicked.  However from that function I dont know which one was clicked.  How do i figure out which one they clicked get the id of it so i can set the visibility of the other ones.

Comment: Use `this` in the event handler, it contains the element that was clicked on.

Comment: To clarify, you want to hide all the ones that were *not* clicked? And  keep the original shown, correct?

Comment: @malcolmdiggs yes I want to hide the other ones cause im going to pull up a review on the product and description but i need to know which was clicked to keep the one there

Comment: It would be better to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of `.setAttribute("onclick","display()")`. Also instead of using the string `"display()"` which will `eval` the string just use a reference to the function: `pic3.addEventListener('click', display, false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pic3 = document.createElement("IMG");
            pic3.setAttribute("src", "img/mutantpre.jpg");
            pic3.setAttribute("onclick", "display('mutantpre')");
            pic3.setAttribute("id", "mutantpre");
            pic3.setAttribute("height", "250px");
            pic3.setAttribute("width", "150px");
            document.getElementById("product4").appendChild(pic3);
```

by passing same id in function of on click you can do this trick

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense! Thank you so much :)

Comment: will do it just told me to wait 8 min

Comment: and you will replicate this code for each picture?!

Comment: @user3491583 I din`t get what you asking for now

Comment: @when u said if it works mark as answer, i tried to do that but it said i have to wait 8 min before i can set your answer as the answer for my question.   I guess stackoverflow has that because it wants you to consider all answers submitted

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this

```
var pic3 = document.createElement("IMG");
                pic3.setAttribute("src", "#");
                pic3.setAttribute("onclick", "display()");
                pic3.setAttribute("id", "mutantpre");
                pic3.setAttribute("height", "250px");
                pic3.setAttribute("width", "150px");
                document.getElementById("product4").appendChild(pic3);

function display(){
   el = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i =0;i<el.length;i++){
   el[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){

      alert("the clicked one's id is "+e.target.id);
    });
        }
}
```

**[Check the working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t4w8/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The display function :

```
function display(element){
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0; i<list.length ; i++){
        list[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }

    element.style.opacity="1";
}
```

And in your code you must have this :

```
 pic3.setAttribute("onclick", "display(this)");
```

**Live example**
http://jsfiddle.net/W65yA/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var activeImage = images[0]; // Assuming the first image is active at first
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    image.onclick = function() {
           activeImage.classList.remove("active");
           this.classList.add("active");
           activeImage = this;
        }
}
```